# MPMoviePlayerViewController | Allow landscape mode

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, landscape

I'm trying to stream a video in my app. The method I've found is :

```
NSURL *theMovieURL = [NSURL URLWithString:self.data.trailer];
        if (theMovieURL)
        {
            self.movieController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:theMovieURL];
            [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:self.movieController];
            [self.movieController.moviePlayer play];
        }
```

I'm not sure if it's the most conventional, but it works.

The problem is that I can't figure out how to allow the landscape mode, for the video only. Should I use something like `shouldAutorotate` or `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation` , and how ?

FYI, the entire app allows only the portrait mode.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 34):

`shouldAutoRotate` is deprecated as of iOS 6 and should be avoided unless you're going for < 6 .

Instead, you'd want to override the `supportedInterfaceOrientations` and `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` methods.

In this case, if you don't want to subclass the media player you could override a method in the app delegate like so:

```
- (NSUInteger) application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    if ([[self.window.rootViewController presentedViewController] isKindOfClass:[MPMoviePlayerViewController class]])
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
    }
    else
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
}
```

Comment: check if the presentedViewController is being dismissed (isBeingDismissed property), otherwise the presenting viewcontroller will show up in landscapemode

Answer (score 17):

@peko says correct way. when user exits from fullscreen video, this method called again with `MPMoviePlayerViewController` class. you should check it is dismissed or not, if you don't, when user exit from video, main window will stay in landscape mode, and also you forgot `MPInlineVideoFullscreenViewController` class. when you use embed player (not fullscreen) it is called with that class name.

I did it like that. it works for me.

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)windowx
{
    if ([[self.window.rootViewController presentedViewController] isKindOfClass:[MPMoviePlayerViewController class]] ||
    [[self.window.rootViewController presentedViewController] isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"MPInlineVideoFullscreenViewController")])
    {
        if ([self.window.rootViewController presentedViewController].isBeingDismissed)
        {
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
        }
        else
        {
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The movie player might not be the first presented view controller, so you should do something like this

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {
    UIViewController* playerController = self.window.rootViewController.presentedViewController;
    while (playerController && ![playerController isKindOfClass:[MPMoviePlayerViewController class]]) {
        playerController = playerController.presentedViewController;
    }
    if (playerController && !playerController.isBeingDismissed) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
    } else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
}
```

Although `MPMoviePlayerViewController` has been deprecated so you should use `AVPlayerViewController` instead and check its class too in this loop.

Answer (score 0):

The best way so far is to implement this AppDelegate function and check if the `rootViewController` has a child of type `AVPlayerViewController` or `MPMoviePlayerViewController` then you return `[.portrait, .landscapeLeft, .landscapeRight]` and else `.portrait`.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if let _ = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.childViewControllers.first as? AVPlayerViewController {
        return [.portrait, .landscapeLeft, .landscapeRight]
    }
    return .portrait
}
```

You should check on the `keyWindow` of `UIApplication` because apple presents this viewController in a another `UIWindow` so if you try to do that check on the window that is declared in the `AppDelegate` this won't work so be careful.