# Allow fullscreen landscape only for system AVPlayerViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, rotation, avplayer

I have an app which uses a `UISplitViewController` to load a webpage in the Detail View Controller, which has a `WKWebView` property. Some of the URLs are links to embedded YouTube videos, and some are direct links to .mp4 files. Either way, the video files are loaded automatically (after tapping for the YouTube videos) into a fullscreen system player, which I assume is an `AVPlayerViewController`. I've seen several posts about subclassing `AVPlayerViewController` to allow the rotation by implementing `supportedInterfaceOrientations`, and other posts which recommended either checking the class of the `UIWindow`'s `rootViewController` `presentedViewController` in `application: supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:` or checking a variable on the `AppDelegate` that was set when the `AVPlayerViewController` was presented, but none of these solutions have worked for me because I'm not creating or presenting my own instance of `AVPlayerViewController`, so I'm not sure how to allow the rotation to landscape when these videos are playing.

Is there a way I can tell when the system is playing a video in full screen mode, so I can allow the rotation?

Here are links to some of the posts I've seen already:

[MPMoviePlayerViewController | Allow landscape mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17276898/mpmovieplayerviewcontroller-allow-landscape-mode/26025794#26025794)

[Only ONE VIEW landscape mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24928057/only-one-view-landscape-mode)

Answer (score 3):

I hope u are still need an answer. I have found solution in Swift, but it is simply convertible in Objective C. I found out, that when using WKWebView (maybe UIWebView, too) full screen video is presented in new UIWindow (at least on iOS 10). That window has blank **UIViewController** and presented **AVFullScreenViewController** over it.

So, in ur AppDelegate u should implement `application:supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:` like this

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if window != self.window, let pvc = window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController, "\(type(of: pvc))" == "AVFullScreenViewController" {
        return pvc.isBeingDismissed ? .portrait : .all
    }
    return .portrait
}
```

While **AVFullScreenViewController** is private API class, u could protect urself and replace `"AVFullScreenViewController"` with `String(format: "AV%@ViewController", "FullScreen")`

Good luck!

Comment: I also had to use `UIDevice.current.setValue(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portriat.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")`